# Error of failed to open stream: Permission denied in laravel using dropzone

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone.js

I am integrate dropzone into laravel 5.4. When i trying to upload the file. Only if the file size are less than 2mb can successfully uploaded. Other than that would be getting error of `failed to open stream: Permission denied` or `PostTooLargeException`.

The localhost i am using is wamp. The post_max_size + upload_max_filesize are changed to 256mb and restarted many time. But still same problems.

This is the code i move the file

```
Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs(
        'files/'. $file->slug,
        $uploadedFile,
        $upload->filename
    );
```

UPDATED: Seem like the problems is caused by localhost configuration. But i changed WAMP setting and restarted the value still did't change.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have the file permissions set correctly and that your web server user can write to your file location.

Comment: How to remove the cache? i tried php artisan cache:clear but did't work.

Comment: `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: If i upload file bigger like 16mb, new error came out `POST Content-Length of 16285043 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0`

But i changed the `post_max_size + upload_max_filesize`, don't know why still same problem.

Comment: @Difster , Currently if the file is less than 2mb will working correctly. Is that still consider of permission problems?

Comment: @masterhunter This is a `post_max_size` error. Have you tried using `echo phpinfo();` to be sure about your changes?

Comment: @masterhunter if it works for small file, There should not be any permission problems

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos i added script into my system. Yes the size still 8mb. Strange, but the WAMP controller is showing 256MB. Any idea what is the problems?

Comment: Is `upload_max_filesize` <= `post_max_size`? How do you declare those values? - Update your question if needed. You have to edit your `php.ini` and restart `WAMP`

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos i updated my question. Please check.

Comment: @masterhunter Are you sure you restarted all the services? Is there by any chance another installation of WAMP?

Answer (score 0):

I founded the solution. 
First create a php scripts with `echo phpinfo();` and check the `upload_max_filesize, post_max_size` , in my case i am using left click WAMP icon> PHP > PHP Settings > update the size. It did't work for me. I need to manually go to `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.ini`, open with notepad and update the `upload_max_filesize, post_max_size` = 16MB.

Final important step after you restart the server. 
Use `php artisan config:cache` to clear the cache.
This work for me.